# Active Record or NHibernate generating invalid Sql for paging on SqlQuery

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

When applying Paging (using `SetFirstResult` and `SetMaxResults`) to an `ActiveRecord` `SqlQuery`, with nHibernate 2.1.1 GA and ActiveRecord 2.0.1 the following sql is generated:

```
SELECT 
    TOP 40 
FROM 
    (, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY account.Name, account.State) as __hibernate_sort_row 
        select  account.Name 
                <rest of query>
    ) as query 
WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > 40 
ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

This errors and moreover doesn't run in sql... whereas it should be

```
SELECT TOP 40  * 
FROM ( 
    SELECT
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY account.Name, account.State) as __hibernate_sort_row 
    ,select  account.Name 
                <rest of query>
) as query 
WHERE query.__hibernate_sort_row > 40 
ORDER BY query.__hibernate_sort_row
```

The odd things are :

- The query without paging works fine
- With paging, page 1 works fine (i.e. first result = 0, maxresult = 40)
- Exactly the same approach works fine for `HqlQuery`, only `SqlQuery` affected.

This applies to MS2005Dialect and MS2008Dialect...

Anyone know my stupid issue ?

Comment: are you doing `select *` in the sql query?

Comment: no. All fields are nominated. I've also aliased them uniquely, it still produces junk sql. I'm adding manually now. Not ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I've found this page [Possible SQL Server bug](http://groups.google.com/group/nhusers/browse_thread/thread/ee7b21f578718dea/209a0ff6ed4d2b21?lnk=gst&q=SetMAxResults&pli=1) which, contra to the title, suggests I'll need to write it in my sql. No problem just could have done without spending half a day trying.

Can anyone confirm this is definitely the case ?

Comment: We're double selecting but that's our solution for now. Needs a retest with NH 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I used a work-around for it. Here its [link](http://afsharm.blogspot.com/2010/11/paging-problem-with-named-sql-queries.html). May be helpful to you.